# Configure Jboss eap 6.2 to use log4j2

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, log4j, jboss6.x, log4j2

Hi I have developed a multiple module j2ee ear deployment and I need to change it's logging configuration to use log4j2.

The deployment package doesn't include any log4j configuration, it uses the jboss default native logging, What I need to do is change the jboss native logging to log4j2. So far I found one way of doing it, that is to include the log4j2 library in each of the module and a log4j config file. But this approach seems very problematic, since if it required to change the logging level I will have to deploy the whole application changing all the log4j config files.

My question is , is they any way that I can change the configuration in Jboss ( not in my app ) to use log4j2 for logging ?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for an answer to this same question and this is what I have discovered.

If you wish to use JBoss's Logging system (defining your logging inside the standalone.xml file), you **CANNOT** use Log4j2 as of JBoss EAP 6.3 (JBoss 7).  JBoss only supports log4j 1.2.X at this time.

Furthermore, you **CANNOT** include the log4j JAR inside your web application. JBoss automatically injects the APIs for log4J 1.2, SLF4J, common-logging and java.util.logging, but only if not included with the application. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Last note: There is no Log4j2->Log4j bridge or other mechanism that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following to your jboss-deployment-structure.xml (included in the war)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
      <!-- 
      Prevent that the server add automatically dependencies -->
      <!-- Exclude all logging dependencies so we can use log4j2 -->
      <exclusions>
         <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
         <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
         <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j" />
         <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
      </exclusions>  
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Then you could include the log4j2 jar in your application and put the log4j2 config file in a file system folder if you add an apprpriate module definition.

This all depends though on the logging api that your application is using - e.g. against which api it is compiled. If you can change it I'd suggest to use slf4j that would be the most flexible solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
The Log4J configuration file is located at server/xxx/conf/jboss-log4j.xml in jboss.

If you use Log4J or Apache Jakarta Commons Logging within your application, you can log your application by adding category entries to the jboss-log4j.xml file. For example, if your application uses the package name org.jbia, you can log the classes in that package and its subpackages by adding a category to the jboss-log4j.xml file, as shown below :

<log4j:...>
<category name="org.jbia">
<priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>
</log4j>
```

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/ I'm trying to use log4j2.. but according to the jboss configuration it seems like not supported by default. what you are suggesting is the way to configure jboss for log4j 1.x isn't it?

Comment: yes , you can configure jboss for log4j like that. I have implemented it in jboss directory and that works fine.

Comment: U mean it works for log4j2 with asynchronous logging ?

Comment: Arjun, I still think you are talking about log4j-1.2.x, not log4j-2.0, or am I missing something? With asynchronous logging you mean the async appender, correct? That is different from the log4j-2.0 async loggers.